# How to get ng-model value from materialize using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, materialize

When i typing the text in search the data will be filter and when i selecting the corrsponding value in radiobutton it will select on the search text field but it wont working

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12">
     <input id="search" class="search nomargin" type="text" class="validate dark" ng-model="search">
   <label for="search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search Player</label>
 </div>
 </div>

     <div class="searchresultsbox z-depth-1">
       <div class="row nopad nomargin">
     <div class="col s12 nopad nomargin">
            <ul ng-repeat="eachPlayer in user |filter:search">
            <li><input name="rdbRisk" type="radio" id="rdbRisk" ng-change="Assign(selected)" ng-value="eachPlayer" ng-model="selected"/>
     {{eachPlayer}} </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modalbuttongroup">
   <a href="" class="center waves-effect waves-light btn addplayer" ng-click="submitPlayer(selected)"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> ADD PLAYER</a>
   <a href="" class="center waves-effect waves-light btn cancelbtn modal-close red"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> CANCEL</a>
</div>
```

here is my js code

```
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.selected;
    $scope.user =

      [{
    "id": "57f2ade2d9913939d0de4af8",
    "firstName": "Sachin"
    "lastName":"Tendulkar"

      }, {
    "id": "57f3d03fd99139333880a2f8",
    "firstName": "Shane"
    "lastName":"Warne"
      }, {
    "id": "57f3d05ad99139333880a2fa",
    "firstName": "Virat"
    "lastName":"Kohli"
      }, {
    "id": "57f3fff6d991394b3daa2d49",
    "firstName": "Ricky"
    "lastName":"Ponting"
      }]

    $scope.Assign = function(user) {
      $scope.selected = user;
    };
    $scope.submitPlayer = function(user) {
      alert(JSON.stringify($scope.selected.id))
    };
  }
]);
```

I want the player name to be displayed in the textfield once the player is selected and and when clicking 'ADD PLAYER' I want the player ID to be alerted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using materialize, you  need to design the form in a certain format, also use the angular-materialize js for the same.

```
<div ng-repeat="eachPlayer in player |filter:player.name">
     <p>
       <input type="radio" id="test1" ng-model="selected" ng-change="Assign(selected)" ng-value="eachPlayer" /> {{eachPlayer.name}} {{selected}}
       <label for="test1">{{eachPlayer.name}}</label>
    </p>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/nb8116u4/6/)

Comment: it always selected in first radio button only check your demo if i select third radio button but it will select only first

Comment: @AraviS its an issue with the materialize ss

Comment: I am only working with bootstrap with angluar its more comfortable but materilaize it little tediuos for integrating. You help me a lot thankyou for everything I am new in this just passout guy So help me thankyou

Comment: If i click B Team but will select only Ateam so id is wrong

Comment: supose if i have two players sanath jayasuriya and sangakara both are same letter initially "san"  two players will come .If I select sangakara ,in this context sangakara is come under second option so if select sanagakara means sanath will select and his id will popup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125869/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-aravi-s).